# Lotus Notes "Unable to locate program" for hyperlink

Tags: google-chrome, lotus-notes

Up till yesterday clicking an hyperlink in Lotus Notes worked fine (launching Google Chrome). Yesterday I upgraded Chrome and now when I click a hyperlink in Notes the following error pops up:

```
Unable to locate program
```

After an internet search I came across [this IBM](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21217673) article which discusses a similar problem with Excel spreadsheets. I've carefully checked the registry for the "File > Open" association for http and https (both identical) and these are set to:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe\" -- \"%1\""
```

This appears correct. I've further done the following:

- Opened a command prompt and navigated to C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application, then ran the command "chrome -- www.bbc.co.uk" and this works.
- Opened Microsoft Word and added a hyperlink to www.bbc.co.uk. Clicked the link and again this works.

The problem appears to be some corruption that only Lotus Notes (v8.5.2) understands. Launching an image file (eg. PNG) works fine. It seems to have been the Chrome upgrade (to v48) itself that has somehow caused the problem. I am unsure if the path to Chrome changed from before to after the installation.

*** EDIT ***

I can confirm that the path to Chrome did change during the installation.

BEFORE:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<ME>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

AFTER:

```
C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

Thanks for pointing this out [rhsatrhs](https://superuser.com/users/128531/rhsatrhs).

Comment: Re-installation is not an option at this time. It would be better to understand and fix the actual problem because even if re-installation were an option and worked, nothing would be learnt.

Comment: Wait is it set to open them in `https` in the Reg? Possibly this could help? [link](http://superuser.com/questions/241016/lotus-notes-wont-open-a-hyperlink-uri-in-a-browser?rq=1)

Comment: Is it an error message that the Notes client shows? Or is it Windows that shows the error message?

Comment: @link: The registry settings for `http` and `https` were identical, I just chose to show the `http` one. @Per: This is a Notes error (not a Windows error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me like your upgrade of Chrome moved the executable file, and you need to tell Notes where it is.

Click on "Online" (or whatever your current location name is) in the lower right corner of your Notes client to make the Locations dialog pop up.  Click the "Edit" button to edit your current location document. Click on the "Internet Browser" tab, and check the settings there. I'm presuming that you've selected "Other" for the Internet browser, and you've got old location of chrome.exe in the Internet browser path.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. That was exactly the setting I needed. After browsing to the chrome.exe application and saving the settings, it started working again.